# iterate over list of tuples in two notations

Tags: python, tuples

I'm iterating over a list of tuples, and was just wondering if there is a smaller notation to do the following:

```
for tuple in list:
    (a,b,c,d,e) = tuple
```

or the equivalent

```
for (a,b,c,d,e) in list:
    tuple = (a,b,c,d,e)
```

Both of these snippits allow me to access the tuple per item as well as as a whole. But is there a notation that somehow combines the two lines into the for-statement? It seems like such a Pythonesque feature that I figured it might exist in some shape or form.

Comment: This is a rare use case. Normally you either need it in parts or as a whole. Needing both is rare, and the first example isn't hard to do in that case, so Python having syntax just for this usage would be pointless.

Comment: Note that the second does strictly more work, as the tuple is unpacked by the for loop, then repacked in the body of the loop. The first example only unpacks the tuple with no re-packing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pythonic way is the first option you menioned:

```
for tup in list:
    a,b,c,d,e = tup
```

Comment: +1. This is simple, clear and easy to read. No point making it harder.

Answer (score 2):

This might be a hack that you could use. There might be a better way, but that's why it's a hack. Your examples are all fine and that's how I would certainly do it.

```
>>> list1 = [(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
>>> for (a, b, c, d, e), tup in zip(list1, list1):
       print a, b, c, d, e
       print tup

1 2 3 4 5
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Also, please don't use `tuple` as a variable name.

Comment: Nice one. Although I wonder why the OP asked the question in the first place.

Comment: calrification: This is not a *hack*, it just seems useless

Comment: Yeah. His examples are all fine. I wonder why he might want to do it in a single statement.

Comment: @jamylak : Yes, but the OP needed something and this is what I could think of. :P

Comment: This is not something you should ever actually do - it's a nice thought exercise, but in reality, this just makes the code harder to read.

Comment: Yes. That's why I said, that his examples are fine and I endorse those. But, since he needed a way, I just made this one up.

Comment: He didn't *need* a way, he asked if there was a notation to combine them - this is indeed an answer (I didn't -1), but it's just not one anyone should use in actual code - I just wanted to say it again as unfortunately people tend not to pay attention to warnings unless they are repeated a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything really built into Python that lets you do this, because the vast majority of the time, you only need to access the tuple one way or the other: either as a tuple or as separate elements. In any case, something like

```
for t in the_list:
    a,b,c,d,e = t
```

seems pretty clean, and I can't imagine there'd be any good reason to want it more condensed than that. That's what I do on the rare occasions that I need this sort of access.

If you just need to get at one or two elements of the tuple, say perhaps `c` and `e` only, and you don't need to use them repeatedly, you can access them as `t[2]` and `t[4]`. That reduces the number of variables in your code, which might make it a bit more readable.